# Showing $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^n \ln(1-e^{-x})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $n>0$. How can I show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^n \ln(1-e^{-x})=0$? I have not been able to apply L'Hospital's rule with any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1-e^{-x})}{x^{-n} }$$

Now since this limit is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, you can apply L'Hospital's Rule *now*.

Comment: Applying L'Hospital's rule as you suggest gives a limit of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. Applying L'Hospital's rule a second time gives the result though. Thanks.

Comment: @rpf Infact according to L'Hopitals rule, we've to take derivative of denominator and numerator until discontinuity is removed.

Answer (score 1):

For small $x$ we can expand in a taylor series to get $x^n \ln(1-e^{-x}) \approx x^n \ln x$. The rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $(1-e^{-x})/x\to 1$ and then write $$x^{n} \log(1-e^{-x})= x^{n} \log\left(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\right)+x^{n}\log x$$ The first term tends to $0\log 1=0$ and second term is a standard limit which tends to $0$. So the final answer is $0$.